# Updating range returns InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to update range of entities in my `DbContext`:

```
var list = await repository.GetList(ids);
foreach (var entity in list)
{
        entity.IsSomething = true;
}

await repository.UpdateRange(list.ToArray());

...

public async Task UpdateRange(TDomain[] domains)
{
    DbSet.UpdateRange(domains); // exception on this line
    DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None)
}
```

When i jump to `DbSet.UpdateRange(domains)` in my code, it throws an exception:

> message:The instance of entity type 'x' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'x' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I added some code to my `Watch` to check whats going on into my `DbContext`.

```
DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
```

In my entries (before `DbSet.UpdateRange(domains);` line) there are two `x` entieties with `IDs` that i passed by `TDomain[] domains`. These `domains` have `State` property set to `Unchanged`.

My question is how to find entieties that `DbContext` blocks to edit because of  tracking? It seems like nothing here is wrong but `Entity Framework` have something diffrent to say.

Configure of `x` entity:

```
var entityTypeBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<x>();

entityTypeBuilder.HasOne(x => ...).WithOne().HasForeignKey<...>(x => ...);
entityTypeBuilder.HasOne(x => ...).WithOne().HasForeignKey<...>(x => ...);
entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(x => ...).WithOne(x => ...).HasForeignKey(x => ...);
entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(x => ...)
                 .WithOne()
                 .HasForeignKey(x => ...);
entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(x => ...);
```

Maybe there is something wrong with child elements, but why `DbContext` not showing it up in `ChangeTracker`?

Comment: try this `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(false);` According to docs: Persists all updates to the data source and optionally resets change tracking in the object context.

Comment: but it crashes on `UpdateRange`, not in `Save`

Answer (score 0):

On `GetList` method i added:

`AsNoTracking()` befor `ToList()` and everything started to work properly